# Unintended Python Looping Behavior

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I wonder if anyone can help explain some strange looping behavior I'm seeing - here's my code:

Everything was working in this part of the code

```
# Loop through ref_df and run Isolation Forest models by CID
for row in ref_df.itertuples():
    # Reference CID from ref_df
    ref = row.CID
    # Filter new_df table
    ref_fil = new_df['CID']==ref
    mod_df = []
    mod_df = new_df[ref_fil]
    mod_df = mod_df.copy()
```

I then added the following code:

```
    # Add differences between dates to mod_df
    mod_df['InvoiceDate']= pd.to_datetime(mod_df['InvoiceDate']) 
    mod_df = mod_df.sort_values(by=['CID', 'InvoiceDate'])
    prev_dates = mod_df.InvoiceDate.shift().fillna(pd.datetime(2019,10,1))
    ddiff = mod_df.InvoiceDate - prev_dates
    ddiff.name = 'DDiff'
    mod_df = pd.concat((mod_df, ddiff), axis=1, copy=False)
    <Then do something here with mod_df>
```

Here's how the code is supposed to work:

- ref_df is a reference dataframe with a list of PartNo's (CID)
- The code loops through each of the CID's in ref_df
- The ref_df CID is used to filter another dataframe new_df for records with the same CID
- This filter eventually becomes a dataframe mod_df
- All of this was working fine, the loop was filtering and creating mod_df dataframes each time it looped
- This morning I added the additional code to calculate the differences between Invoice Dates in mod_df

The output I'm seeing in mod_df looks like this:

```
       CID  InvoiceDate  DDiff   DDiff   DDiff
1005    18  2019-10-02 0 days  1 days  1 days
1720    18  2019-10-03 0 days  1 days  1 days
4187    18  2019-10-09 0 days  6 days  6 days
7263    18  2019-10-16 0 days  7 days  7 days
9476    18  2019-10-19 0 days  3 days  3 days
11923   18  2019-10-24 0 days  5 days  5 days
12626   18  2019-10-25 0 days  1 days  1 days
13361   18  2019-10-28 0 days  3 days  3 days
20446   18  2019-11-08 0 days 11 days 11 days
```

What's strange about this is the output is after one loop (with a 'break' added to the code) the code `mod_df = []` should clear mod_df each time the code loops. I have no clue why 3 DDiff columns are being added to mod_df? After one loop there should be one DDiff column and it will be cleared with the rest of mod_df when the next loop starts. The first DDiff column is populated with 0's this is unintended too.

Can anyone shed any light as to what might be happening here?

Many thanks in advance for your help....

As requested here's ddiff:

```
1005     1 days
1720     1 days
4187     6 days
7263     7 days
9476     3 days
11923    5 days
12626    1 days
```

As requested here's ref_df:

```
          CID  OrderQty InvoiceDate
0          18        25   10/2/2019
1     1000736        40  10/14/2019
2     1015387        35   10/4/2019
3     1020700        20   10/1/2019
4     1038702        45   10/8/2019
```

CID = 18 is the key that is being used to filter mod_df above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, found the problem line:

```
 mod_df = pd.concat((mod_df, ddiff), axis=1, copy=False)
```

use another name here..

```
mod_df_1 = pd.concat((mod_df, ddiff), axis=1, copy=False)
```

So, the issue was it's the number of times you run the code it will append DDiff as mod_df is keeping on concatenating it with ddiff ...

Comment: Hi Sandeep, thanks for the suggestion. I changed to new_mod_df and the code is doing the same thing - I get 3 columns Ddiff on the first loop.

Comment: Yes sir - changed everything below to new_mod_df

Comment: ok.. thanks... can you print ddiff before concat ..

Comment: also, if you can share the content of ref_df so that I can check this locally. of course, only if it's ok to do so.

Comment: Hi Sandeep - I attached the data you requested to the original post (above)

Comment: Thanks, figured the issue and updated the answer.. pls check ... this willl fix the issue: mod_df_1 = pd.concat((mod_df, ddiff), axis=1, copy=False)